Learn typewriting (typing) app
Many years ago I've improved my typewriting (typing) skills by following along an old-school-app, programmed in the 90s, loaded from a CD-ROM. I don't remember its name, and I am not looking for it here.
Instead I am looking for an app (or a course) that teaches me how to  improve my typewriting skills.

Breaking old bad habits in a gentle but effective way.
Optimized for learning to type on a computer keyboard (perhaps even a German keyboard), not a simple electrical typewriter
Ideal would be an app that does an analysis of my current skill level and generates a personalized syllabus or sequence of lectures

Linux, WebApp, Mac, Android/ChromeOS, Windows is my order of preferences of OSes; free or non-free software

A typing learning program will accustom you to type while looking at the screen not the paper. Nevertheless you want to use a program please try Typing Master.
